# Webservice or WCF or what

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services

I have an application that users access via phone (touchtone) or SMS.
Now want to give them web access.
Thought a webservice communicating with app via TCP would do it.

TCPClient connection code that works OK in the app fails in the webservice with 'Host actively refused connection'

Makes me think that IIS won't allow a Webservice  to drive straight into the local network.
But I am just guessing.

So...
What is the DotNet answer to this.

1) An IIS setting, config file etc that needs adjusting.

2) Forget Webservice and use WCF which I know nothing about.

3) Something else.

Thanks
Bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing too much about your setup, I'd say it's a network permissions problem.

A .Net webservice simply runs as an app under an account on the machine.  If that account doesn't have permission to establish a TCP connection for whatever reason, it will fail in this way.

Check what account your webservice is running as and make sure it has permissions to establish the connection.

Comment: Set authentication mode = "None" in Web.Config file. Thanks

Comment: Ahh, ok - the client was getting the error, not the web service.  Gotcha.